# Chrome treats document.location.href differently?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

on the following URL: www.example.com/page/#2221

- Chrome will return `www.example.com/page/#` for `document.location.href`
- Firefox will return `www.example.com/page/#2221` for `document.location.href`

Is there another alternative to have them both return `www.example.com/page/#2221`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
function getUrl() {
  var location = document.location.href,
      locationLength = location.length,
      hash = document.location.hash;

    if (hash 
        && location.substring(locationLength - 1, locationLength) == '#') {
        location += hash;
    }

    return location;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/xCsFK/).

They return the same thing in Firefox 3.6.13 and Chrome 9.

Though I've always used `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.location` is deprecated. Try using `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: window.location.href returns www.example.com/